# CSRF token missing or incorrect - Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-csrf, csrf-token

I'm trying to build a Django webapp to test the functionalities of a Forex Converter I installed with `pip`. I created an application with `django-startapp Converter` and routed the url `/convert` to the view `convert_view()`.

This is my `views.py` file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates

# Create your views here.

def convert_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        c = CurrencyRates()
        print(c.convert('EUR', 'RON', request.POST.get('eur')))
    context = {}
    return render(request, "convert.html", context)
```

Also, because my view returns a template `convert.html`, I created a form there. This is my `convert.html`:

```
{% csrf_token %}

<form action="." method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="eur" placeholder="EUR">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

As you can see, just a simple page that has a form inside it, redirects to the same page and uses `POST` to send the data. It also uses the `{% csrf_token %}` tag, so there shouldn't be any problems.

When I navigate to `/convert` everything works fine. I type in the amount of money I like to convert from EUR to RON, but when I send the POST request, I get redirected to an error page, telling me:

> CSRF token missing or incorrect.

I read another article on stack overflow about not using `request` as a parameter in the `render()` function, but I'm doing it.

What is wrong? What can I do to fix this error? Thank you.

Comment: `{% csrf_token %}` needs to be inside `<form>` tag. See the page source code - `{% csrf_token %}` generates an `<input>` and if you dont put this input in the form, then the value is not getting send.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko Thank you so much! That's actually my first time working with Django and didn't know about this. Could you put this in a proper answer, so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please put `{% csrf_token %}` inside `<form>` tag. This will solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

`{% csrf_token %}` should be inside the form tag.
like this

```html
<form action="." method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
       <input type="text" name="eur" placeholder="EUR">
       <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The reason behind that is because `{% csrf_token %}` is rendered like this, and inorder input to be submitted along with form it needs to be inside form element.

````html
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="0gdrskkUXOTenFZOWxhzQPZWavohLKrEaOm0aKj8KzOfeLFah9PihEdYG24Fl4F7">```
````

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `{% csrf_token %}` inside the `<form>` tag like this:

```
<form action="." method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="eur" placeholder="EUR">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is error in your form file, your csrf_token is expected to be inside your  tag because django is expecting it with the form data as to certify that what you are sending is safe. Try this

```
   <form action="." method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
           <input type="text" name="eur" placeholder="EUR">
           <input type="submit">
     </form>
```

It will work that way.